# I got this error on early stopping function TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float' in python

Tags: python, deep-learning, floating-point, conv-neural-network, non-type

I am working on epilepsy prediction using CNN and I use early stopping in my code. I got this error `line 230 in on_epoch_end if current > self.value: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float'` I don't know how to fix this error.

`current=non value` and `self.value=0.4021`

Any help would be appreciated.

```
class EarlyStoppingByLossVal(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, monitor='val_loss', value=0.00001, verbose=0, lower=True):
        super(keras.callbacks.Callback, self).__init__()
        self.monitor = monitor
        self.value = value
        self.verbose = verbose
        self.lower=lower

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        current = logs.get(self.monitor)
        if self.lower:
            if current < self.value:
                if self.verbose > 0:
                    print("Epoch %05d: early stopping THR" % epoch)
                self.model.stop_training = True
        else:
            if current > self.value:
                if self.verbose > 0:
                    print("Epoch %05d: early stopping THR" % epoch)
                self.model.stop_training = True

history=model.fit_generator(generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, filesPath, end=75), #end=75),#It take the first 75%
                                validation_data=generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, filesPath, start=75),#start=75), 
                                steps_per_epoch=int((len(filesPath)-int(len(filesPath)/100*25))),#*25), 
                                validation_steps=int((len(filesPath)-int(len(filesPath)/100*75))),#*75),
                                verbose=2,class_weight="balanced",
                                epochs=15, max_queue_size=2, shuffle=True, callbacks=[callback,checkpoint])
```

Comment: What are you storing in variable `current`?

Comment: If you want to put a band-aid without investigating the actual problem, check if `current` is `none` and in such case assign it some default float value.

Comment: @PM77-1 How can I choose the default float value ??

Comment: Can you add the code snippet of how you are calling `model.fit`?

Comment: @MuntasirWahed Sure. Done

Comment: @MuntasirWahed result of  `print(logs.keys())` is dict_keys(['val_loss', 'val_accuracy', 'loss', 'accuracy'])